# ls -F/--classify marks every file as an executable

Tags: bash, shell, mount, partition, ls

`ls -F` classifies *ALL* files on my mounted partitions as an executable (it appends an asterisk to the end of the file name).

The same command performs correctly in other places like my home folder, so I have no idea what is making it misbehave.

```
~
❯ cd /tmp && mkdir somefolder && cd somefolder

/tmp/somefolder 
❯ touch file{0..3}

/tmp/somefolder 
❯ ls -F
file0  file1  file2  file3

/tmp/somefolder 
❯ cd /mnt/sdd2 && mv /tmp/somefolder . && cd somefolder

/mnt/sdd2/somefolder 
❯ ls -F
file0*  file1*  file2*  file3*
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every filesystem type supports file permissions. I suspect yours is one that doesn't, such as FAT32. On these kinds of filesystems, Linux treats everything as executable by default, since executables lacking the execute bit breaks things, but non-executables having the execute bit doesn't. If you don't want any files on it to be executable, you can do that by mounting it with the `fmask=0111` mount option. (Or `fmask=0155` or `fmask=0177` if you don't want group/other to have write or any access to any files.) If you want some files to have the execute bit but not others, then you have to wipe it and reformat it with a different permission type that does support file permissions, such as ext4 (but note that doing so will prevent other operating systems such as Windows from accessing it without third-party drivers).

Comment: You're right, my mounted partition is NTFS. I wish there's an easy and safe way to reformat partitions while keeping your files when you don't have free drives hanging around, but oh well.